# Difference between 'where' and 'And' in in line view query join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, where-clause, inline

I had read in this thread below that there is no difference in the data returned in a query where you either have a Where predicate after the join or an 'And':

[description of difference between 'where' and 'And' in join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302649/difference-between-where-and-and-clause-in-join-sql-query)

However I do have different row counts in my query, which is using an in-line view query in my overall statement, when I change AND/WHERE. I have noticed that the issue is happening when I use a row number over statement in my in line query.

The reason I am using this is to restrict records in the in line query to only the first date record, so I can return subsequent but related records from the outer query.

However when I change the WHERE to an AND I get different number of rows.

My query is similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      table1.userID,
      table2.UniqueID,
      table3.entrydate,
      table2.entrytime,
      table4.changedatestart,
      table2.changetimestart,
      table5.changedateend,
      table2.changetimeend,
      table6.leavedate,
      table2.leavetime,
      table7.nationality_ID,
      table8.reg_code
      FROM
      table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.t1_KEY=table2.t2_KEY)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table4 ON (change_start_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.change_date_start_KEY)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table5 ON (change_end_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.change_date_end_KEY)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table3 ON (entry_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.ENTRY_DATE_KEY)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table6 ON (leave_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.LEAVE_DATE_KEY)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN table7 ON (table7.nat_KEY=table2.nat_KEY)
       INNER JOIN table8 ON (table8.reg_DEPT_KEY=table2.reg_DEPT_KEY)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.table9 ON (table9.leave_KEY=table2.leave_KEY)
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 
        table1.userID UID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table1.userID ORDER BY table3.entrydate ASC) as Seq,
        table2.UniqueID "Unique_ID",
        table3.entrydate "entry_date",
        table2.entrytime "entry_time",
        table4.changedatestart "change_start_Date",
        table2.changetimestart "change Start Time",
        table5.changedateend "change End Date",
        table2.changetimeend "change End Time",
        table6.leavedate "leave Date",
        table2.leavetime "leave time",
        table7.nationality_ID "Nationality ID",
        table8.reg_code "Registration Code"
        FROM
        table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.t1_KEY=table2.t2_KEY)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table4 ON (change_start_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.change_date_start_KEY)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table5 ON (change_end_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.change_date_end_KEY)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table3 ON (entry_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.ENTRY_DATE_KEY)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN DATETIMETABLE  table6 ON (leave_date_alias.DATEKEY=table2.LEAVE_DATE_KEY)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN table7 ON (table7.nat_KEY=table2.nat_KEY)
        INNER JOIN table8 ON (table8.reg_DEPT_KEY=table2.reg_DEPT_KEY)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.table9 ON (table9.leave_KEY=table2.leave_KEY)
        WHERE table3.entrydate  BETWEEN  '20131201'  AND  '20140531'
        AND table8.reg_DESC  In  ( 'Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5'  )
        AND table9.leave_CODE IN ('11','15','16','22','25','27','54','57','66')
        )b
    ON b.UID = table1.userID
    **AND b.Unique_ID <> table2.UniqueID**
    AND b.Seq = 1
    AND b.[Registration Code] = table8.reg_code << If this line is commented out the same row count is returned whether WHERE/AND is used in not equal to ID statement:

AND/WHERE b.Unique_ID <> table2.UniqueID
```

But if I reintroduce the last lin and change the WHERE/AND used in the not equal to ID statement it gives slightly more rows when using the AND statement as opposed to the WHERE predicate.

Comment: Just added that to my original post - it's sql server 2005

Comment: You're referencing table C, which is a part of your derived table, in the outer query, and further, you're joining it to the derived table E.  I'm a little surprised this doesn't raise an error, but I'm not surprised it gives unexpected results.  And how does E even have a column f, if you don't include it in the derived table's select list?

Comment: Can you paste the actual code please? This one is very misleading.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I can't post specific table names and columns verbatim as it's confidential but I will try and change the names in the actual query and post it.

Comment: Original post I have added query but using aliases and simplified explanation of problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the original edit, you had `inner join` in example, thus I asked you to post the original code.

Please keep in mind, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is very very different from `INNER JOIN` in handling the `ON` clause. In a `right outer join`, you get all the records from the right table **irrespective** of the `AND` on the right table.

So, in the below query,

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Id
AND TABLE2.ID = 2
```

you get all the records from Table2 *even* when you have put `TABLE2.ID = 2`. It just has no effect. Whereas, in the below query,

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Id
WHERE TABLE2.ID = 2
```

You will get records only for  `TABLE2.ID = 2`.

But for an inner join, both the below queries are similar:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Id
AND TABLE2.ID = 2
SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Id
WHERE TABLE2.ID = 2
```

So please handle `AND` conditions with care when you are not talking about `RIGHT JOINS`!

I had a similar question sometime back which I had asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27529423/2993606).

Comment: Can you explain what join of the query you are discussing please? I have had 'inner join' for the join between outer query and sub-query the whole time if this is what you are pointing at. Thanks.

Comment: You are having something like table2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN....... <Subquery>b. Thus, the condition `AND b.Unique_ID <> table2.UniqueID` is quite different from `WHERE b.Unique_ID <> table2.UniqueID`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying from the link you gave and the description above but I am looking at the joins for the last condition (table 8), which is affecting the returned results when I use <and/where> and there is no outer join on that table 8. Table 8 uses inner join so from that I would assume that changing AND/WHERE for unique ID shouldn't make any difference to the returned results, which it does unless I remove last statement for join to table 8.